# Content Density being ignored in SAPUI5 1.71.4 on Desktop sapUiSizeCozy

Tags: sapui5

I've upgraded our gateway to FES 6 and I've brought in apps from 1.52 to 1.71, by doing so, content density on Desktop is no longer working.

Typically, we'd force content density cozy on Desktop and Mobile as these apps are used on TouchScreen desktops.

In the Manifest.json:

```
"contentDensities": {
        "compact": false,
        "cozy": true
    },
```

This alone typically works, but as it didn't I've also added to my view.xml:

```
<mvc:View controllerName="com.****.ic.controller.***" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="sapUiSizeCozy" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" displayBlock="true" xmlns="sap.m">
```

However, in the body class of the generated app "sapUiSizeCompact" is still present instead of cozy:
[image: Here's a picture of the Source view in Chrome]

Other things I've tied:
Inside Component.js

```
getContentDensityClass : function () {
        this._sContentDensityClass = "sapUiSizeCozy";
        return this._sContentDensityClass;
    },
```

Inside Controller onInit:

```
this.getView().addStyleClass(this.getOwnerComponent().getContentDensityClass());
```

Has anyone experienced this issue at SAP UI5 1.7+ ? Previously just the manifest.json entries were sufficient.

Comment: Not 100% sure but I think compact is stronger than cozy (in the CSS). Your launchpad detects which fits best and sets that on a global (body) level. Whatever you do in your app is a few levels deeper. If it was the other way round (LP cozy, app compact) it would work (I guess). Also not sure if this was recently introduced or always has been that way.

Comment: This will be new, we went from SAP_UI 752 to 754 SP02 (FES2->FES6) and now encounter this problem. I believe some custom css to essentially re-create cozy will be required.

Comment: Hi this is an old Thread but.. do you found any Solution ? ill tryed it to set it to the body and app container.. but yeah nothing helps.

Comment: No, in the end SAP recommended that I created a custom launchpad extension which fixed the issue

Answer (score 1):

According to SAP Note 2538389, Cozy vs Compact in a Fiori Launchpad is now forced by the device type (phone/tablet vs desktop).

However, if your desktop device has a touch screen, you can change this in the user settings - people menu (top right) -> settings -> appearance.

I'm not sure if there is a way to default this setting across all users though.

Edit: Also, it's worth updating to the latest SAPUI5 version (1.71.21 at time of writing) following the instructions on note 2856654.

Comment: Thank you orogers for that excellent reply, SAP_UI 754 SP04 release in about a week, I'll grab that and see if it makes any difference. It's such a shame the manifest over-write doesn't work anymore like it did in 1.52 or 1.38.
If personalization settings for device can be set similarly en-masse to others, that'll be one way around it. I think I'll end up having to deploy css for every app we convert.

Comment: You can write a launchpad plugin which removes the global body class. This should be way easier than adding CSS to every app.